# ArrayStoreException on JUNG VisualizationImageServer initialization

Tags: java, maven, jung

I'm trying to get a basic JUNG graph example running - I was able to get the following code to run in a standalone java program but when I put the same code in a server-side jar built using Maven, it fails with a ArrayStoreException on the VisualizationImageServer initialization:

```
public Response getGraph() throws IOException {
    //log.info("Starting graph rendering");
    try {
        DirectedSparseGraph<String, Number> g = new DirectedSparseGraph();
        String[] v = createVertices(10); 
        createEdges(v); 
        vv =  new VisualizationImageServer<String,Number>(new KKLayout<String,Number>(graph), new Dimension(600,600)); 
        renderGraph(vv);
        ...}
```

This line fails:

```
        vv =  new VisualizationImageServer<String,Number>(new KKLayout<String,Number>(graph), new Dimension(600,600));
```

Error message snippet:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.KKLayout
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.layout.ObservableCachingLayout.<init>(ObservableCachingLayout.java:50)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.DefaultVisualizationModel.setGraphLayout(DefaultVisualizationModel.java:91)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.DefaultVisualizationModel.<init>(DefaultVisualizationModel.java:74)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.BasicVisualizationServer.<init>(BasicVisualizationServer.java:150)
    at edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationImageServer.<init>(VisualizationImageServer.java:40)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that on your server side code, you have more than one version of jung that conflict with each other.
On line 50 of `ObservableCachingLayout` in jung-visualization version 2.0, the delegate (`KKLayout`) is added to a `org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer[]` array, because the `KKLayout` delegate is (supposed to be) an instance of a `Transformer`.
Your array store exception that calls out the `KKLayout` as the problem makes me think that the earlier version 2.0 of `ObservableCachingLayout` is getting a version 2.1 or later `KKLayout` delegate (from jung-algorithms) that is not a `Transformer`, but is instead a `com.google.common.base.Function`.
I can't verify that this is the actual problem, but I believe that this theory addresses a possible cause of the specific errors you are seeing.

Comment: This worked, thank you - I had jung-api and jung-graph-impl at 2.1.1 and jung-visualization at 2.0.1 - fixed and works fine